# Contains not working with List (overrided equals/hash code not executing)

Tags: android, list, equals, contains

I am having a problem, I want to check if `name` is contained within a `List<ReceiptItem> receiptItemList;` with `if(!receiptItemList.contains(name))`. I have overrided the hashCode and equals methods, But they are not being executed and that IF check just passes by not giving me `Log.i("LOG","Double Product");`. And just to add as a note there are items inside the List and I am getting them out.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here? why aren't they being executed.

Here is the code:

**Fragment Code**

```
String name = "";
double price = 0;
List<ReceiptItem> receiptItemList;

    name = db.readFromCategoriesAndGetOneProduct(category, product).getName();   
    price = db.readFromCategoriesAndGetOneProduct(category, product).getPrice();



    if(!receiptItemList.contains(name)) 
    {

    receiptItemList.add(new ReceiptItem(name,1,price); //name, ammount, price

    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("LOG","Double Product"); //for testing purposes 
    }
```

**ReceiptItem Class**

```
public class ReceiptItem {

private String description;
private int ammount;
private double price;

public ReceiptItem() {

}

public ReceiptItem(String description, int ammount, double price) {
    this.description = description;
    this.ammount = ammount;
    this.price = price;

}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public int getAmmount() {
    return ammount;
}

public void setAmmount(int ammount) {
    this.ammount = ammount;
}

public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return description.hashCode();
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    Log.i("info","equals");     //for testing but this doesnt even show up
    if (o instanceof ReceiptItem) {
        ReceiptItem other = (ReceiptItem) o;
         return description.equals(other.description) ;

    } else {
        return false;
    }


   }
}
```

Comment: `name` isn't an instance of a "ReceiptItem", but your log should still show up.

Comment: But it doesn't, and I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Try a direct comparison. Make two `ReceiptItem` objects with the same name and compare them and then try and compare it with a string directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing ReceiptItem with String.

Try create ReceiptItem before and compare then.

```
ReceiptItem item = new ReceiptItem(name,1,price);
if(!receiptItemList.contains(item)) 
{

receiptItemList.add(item); //name, ammount, price

}
```

Your equals() is not calling, because implementation of contains() use

```
o.equals(elementData[i])
```

So, equals from String class is calling (if name is String)